# Python why does int("0") return false

Tags: python, validation, int, string-conversion

I am trying to learn Python and can, for the life of it, not figure out, why this:

```
i = raw_input("enter a number")

if int(i):
    print "yes"
else:
    print "false"
```

would not return true if i == "0"

Background:
I am trying to implement  Union-Find Algorithm. Everything works fine, but when I try to connect two points and one is 0 it won't let me through the control. 
(Python 2.7)

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html)

Comment: What exactly do you check when you "try to connect two points"?

Comment: I was building a Union-Find Algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python types has boolean value, defined in [special methods](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). in particular, `0`, `None`, `False`, `""` (and any other empty sequence) are false.

Obviously,

```
>>> int("0")
0
```

What's more, the value of `False` is 0, and the value of `True` is 1, for most purposes (except for their representation as strings, and their `type`, which is `bool`):

```
>>> 0 == False
True
```

Comment: Thank you. Though duskast had the right way to solve the problem at hand, you answered the question.

Answer (score 4):

I think you meant `i.isdigit()` instead of `int(i)`.

Comment: yes, my thought process was: if it is possible to convert you into an int, then lets move on. But because of Elazar's answer I now know why that was the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2):

Because `0` is falsy, just like `None`, `[]`, `{}` and `False` (and a few more objects). It's not explicitly false, but it evaluates to `False` when used as a condition.

If you want to check that `i` is a number, assume that it is a number:

```
try:
    n = int(i)
    print "That's a number"
except ValueError:
    print "That's not a number"
```